# Difficulty in subsetting multiple .nc files

Tags: r, crop, tiff, netcdf, terra

I am using following code in R to subset a .nc file. It is running successfully.
My problem is that when I am modifying the code for multiple .nc files, it is not working and giving me error.

Code for 1 .nc file

```
library(terra)    

#Select single file
files = rast("File1.nc")

#Define spatial extent 
extent<-c(37,44, 7,12)     #Left Long, RIght Long. Lower Lat, Upper Lat

#Subsetting
datasubset<- crop(files,extent)

writeRaster(datasubset, filename='File.tif', overwrite=TRUE)
```

Code for multiple .nc files

```
library(terra)    

#Select multiple .nc files
files = list.files("D:/Test/", pattern = '*.nc', full.names = TRUE)

#Define spatial extent 
extent<-c(37,44, 7,12)     #Left Long, RIght Long. Lower Lat, Upper Lat

#Subsetting
datasubset<- crop(files,extent)
```

After this tep, it gives error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘crop’ for signature ‘"character"’
```

Could anyone please tell how to modify the code to consider multiple .nc files.

Comment: Applying a set of functions to multiple files is a common requirement: have you tried any of these solutions yet? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+apply+function+over+multiple+files